# Max value from multiple criteria with VLOOKUP

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I want to find and display the highest number based on a grouping.  Column A has a group of names with an item number at the end.   Column C has individual item names and Column D has a number associated with that item name.  The VLOOKUP I currently have searches the grouping to return the number associated with that item. What I want to do is search all the items in the grouping and return the highest value from Column D.  Formula I'm using now =VLOOKUP(MID(A2,1,FIND("-",A2,1)-1),C2:D41,2,FALSE)

[image]

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends which version of Excel you use. 3 proposals below on the screenshot.
[image: lookup]